# jQuery toggle div with <select> field

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I've been trying for about an hour to get this code to work but it is just a pain in the dark place.

Okay, lets cut to the chase. I'm trying to make a select field that toggles different HTML elements based on the status of the `<select>`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySelect').change(function() {
    let item1 = $("#item1");
    let item2 = $("#item2");
    let item3 = $("#item3");

    switch ($('select[name=mySelect]').val()) {
      case 1:
        item1.show();
        item2.hide();
        item3.hide();
        break;
      case 2:
        item1.hide();
        item2.show();
        item3.hide();
        break;
      case 3:
        item1.hide();
        item2.hide();
        item3.show();
        break;
      default:
        item1.hide();
        item2.hide();
        item3.hide();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>-- Select your item--</option>
  <option value="1">item1</option>
  <option value="2">item2</option>
  <option value="3">item3</option>
</select>

<div id='item1'>
  <p> contents
</div>

<div id='item2'>
  <p> text2</p>
</div>

<div id='item3'>
  <p> text3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `#selectRange`?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. I forgot to change the Id of the select field  in my code. It's fixed now :D

Comment: Thanks. I've added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your current logic is that you're retrieving a string from `val()` and comparing it to an int in the `switch`, hence the `default` block is always executed as the comparison fails. To fix that compare to a string, or convert the `val()` to an int.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySelect').change(function() {
    let item1 = $("#item1");
    let item2 = $("#item2");
    let item3 = $("#item3");

    switch ($('select[name=mySelect]').val()) {
      case '1':
        item1.show();
        item2.hide();
        item3.hide();
        break;
      case '2':
        item1.hide();
        item2.show();
        item3.hide();
        break;
      case '3':
        item1.hide();
        item2.hide();
        item3.show();
        break;
      default:
        item1.hide();
        item2.hide();
        item3.hide();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>-- Select your item--</option>
  <option value="1">item1</option>
  <option value="2">item2</option>
  <option value="3">item3</option>
</select>

<div id='item1'>
  <p> contents
</div>

<div id='item2'>
  <p> text2</p>
</div>

<div id='item3'>
  <p> text3</p>
</div>
```

**However**, you can achieve your goal in a much sompler way by putting a common class on all the `div` elements so that you can easily hide them all when the selection changes. Then you can build the id selector string by concatenating the selected value, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySelect').change(function() {
    $('.item').hide();
    $('#item' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>-- Select your item--</option>
  <option value="1">item1</option>
  <option value="2">item2</option>
  <option value="3">item3</option>
</select>

<div class="item" id="item1">
  <p>contents</p>
</div>

<div class="item" id="item2">
  <p>text2</p>
</div>

<div class="item" id="item3">
  <p>text3</p>
</div>
```

Note that you will not be able to select your disabled `option` element so there is no need to show all the `.item` elements again as your `default` block attempts to do.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.